# Matlab operation to Python

Tags: python, matlab

I'm having trouble translating this operation from MatLab to Python:

```
xup(1:ncomp,1)=aa(1+k:ncomp+k).';
```

"aa" is a vector of 1x1000 elements.

"ncomp" = 128

"k" is a variable for a loop cycle.

The problem is ... I don't understand how does it work.

I'm posting the whole section of the algorithm:

```
while(testnorm>0.0001 && epoca<maxit)
    k=0;
    xup=[];
 
    while(k<=npatt)   
       xup(1:ncomp,1)=aa(1+k:ncomp+k).';

       if (funz==1)
       gy=tanh(alpha.*xup.'*w);
       else
       gy=sign(xup.'*w).*log(1+abs(alpha*xup.'*w));
       end
  
       w=w+lr.*(xup*gy-w*triu((xup.'*w).'*gy));
       w = w / norm(w);
  
       k=k+1;
   end
   [...]
end
```

can you help ?

Comment: MATLAB's online documentation and tutorials are very good. Did you try looking through them to figure out your problem? Did you try actually executing the code? Even if you don't have MATLAB, GNU Octave is largely code-compatible, especially for something as simple as this, and there is even an [online interpreter](https://ideone.com) available.

Comment: This is a plain indexing operation, which can be trivially translated to NumPy. Note that the `.'` at the end is transposing a vector, which is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially what this

```
xup(1:ncomp,1)=aa(1+k:ncomp+k).';
```

line is doing; It is fetching data from vector aa, starting from index 1+k to ncomp+k index(i.e ncomp total elements) and transposing(from single row to ncomp rows) those elements. Now this transposed data is being inserted into the xup as ncomp rows, where each row has a single element. The similar python code would be

```
import numpy as np
aa = np.array([i for i in range(1000)])
ncomp = 128
k = 0
xup = [[0] for i in range(ncomp)]

while(k<10):
    data = (np.transpose(aa[k:ncomp+k]))
    for i in range(ncomp):
        xup[i] = data[i]
    k += 1
    
print(xup[:128])
```

Comment: This is overly complex. `xup` should be a NumPy array as well, then you don’t need to loop. Transposing a vector is pointless. Also look up `np.arange`.

Comment: Thanks Cris for the feedback. I totally agree with your comment.

Comment: Yes, I know ... this code I'm working with has a lot of wrong parts ...
I'm my language, we'd call "dirty code".

BTW, I assume the transposition of the vector is a generalization: probably it's taken from some math theorem that works on matrices and they ported in on matlab integrally, without caring if "aa" was a vector or a matrix.

Anyway, what should I do without transposition and loop ?

`XUP = np.arange(aa[k:ncomp+k])`

is this correct ?